# Mac OSX - Firefox --new-tab option doesn't work

Tags: macos, firefox

I was trying to force a new tab to open in firefox via a terminal command.

If I run `/Applications/Firefox.app/Contents/MacOS/firefox --help`, it tells me that there is a `--new-tab <url>` parameter.

But when I make use of it, firefox reports:

`Close Firefox
A copy of Firefox is already open. Only one copy of Firefox can be open at a time.`

Googling online revealed reasons and a potential workaround:

- https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1130718
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=393645

I tried the workaround AppleScript, but it only worked on the first run attempt, and failed on every other occasion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I mainly posted the question as a means to document and share my solution.

I made use of what I believe to be Ivan Enderlin's Apple Script, "**ffnewtab.scpt**". The only addition I made to it was to add a one second delay (the "**delay 1**" line) between activating firefox and creating a new tab. It seemed as though on my system, the script ran too fast and didn't give firefox enough time for the new tab to open, probably due to my macbook being somewhat old and slow:

```
on firefoxRunning()
  tell application "System Events" to (name of processes) contains "Firefox"
end firefoxRunning

on run argv

  if (firefoxRunning() = false) then
    do shell script "open -a Firefox " & (item 1 of argv)
  else
    tell application "Firefox" to activate

    delay 1

    tell application "System Events"
      keystroke "t" using {command down}
      keystroke item 1 of argv & return
    end tell
  end if
end run
```

Then it runs fine for me with:

`osascript ffnewtab.scpt <url>`